# How to make a menu selected using mouse over constant till user select an option in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two images, on `mouseover` event of this two images there are corresponding  two menu bars gets displayed.
I need to select an option in the menu but on  `mouseout`, the menu is disappearing.

What can I do to make it better?

Below is my code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
     {
            $("#Image1").mouseover(function () {
                $("#one").show();
            });
            $("#Image1").mouseout(function () {
                $("#one").hide();
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Image2").mouseover(function () {
                $("#two").show();
            });
            $("#Image2").mouseout(function () {
                $("#two").hide();
            });
        });

    </script>    
      <div id='one'style="border: 10px double #CCCCCC; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #92DF7B; width: 134px; height: 142px; position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 420px; ">
               <ul>
                   <li>General</li>
                   <li>Policy</li>
                   <li>Manuals</li>
                   <li>HEXA Documents</li>
                   <li>ISO</li>
               </ul>
           </div>
            <div id='two' style="color: #FFFFFF;  background-color: #92DF7B; position: absolute; top: 159px; left: 35px; width: 131px; height: 152px; display:none;">
                 <ul>
                     <li>General</li>
                     <li>Policy</li>
                     <li>Manuals</li>
                     <li>HEXA Documents</li>
                     <li>ISO</li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
        <div style="border-color: #FFFFFF; position:absolute; top:176px; left: 188px; height: 403px; width: 534px;">

            <asp:Image  ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                   ImageUrl="~/Images/New Bitmap Image(1).bmp" Width="180px" 
                 CssClass="class1" Height="96px" />

               <br />

               <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                   ImageUrl="~/Images/New Bitmap Image (2).bmp" />

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
     {
            $("#Image1").mouseover(function () {
                $("#one").show();
                 $("#two").hide();
            });

            $("#one").mouseout(function () {
                $("#one").hide();
            });

        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Image2").mouseover(function () {
                $("#two").show();
                $("#one").hide();
            });

            $("#two").mouseout(function () {
                $("#two").hide();
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: This is not working :(, i cant select an option from menu , when i click on menu its getting hidden

Comment: yeah thats what... i am hiding menu after clicking on it... if you don't want it then let me remove that

Comment: But i cant click on menu ,on mouse over only the menu gets hidden. I want user to select an option from this menu and if he does not , on mouse over of second image the menu corresponding to first image should be hidden. I am confused.

Comment: can you share jsfiddle of it?

Comment: you are welcome :), also if you want to hide menu one if mouse over image2 and vice versa ..pls see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Only hide menu  on li click ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
 {
        $("#Image1").mouseover(function () {
            $("#one").show();
        });



        $("#one li").click(function () {
            $("#one").hide();
        });

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Image2").mouseover(function () {
            $("#two").show();
        });



       $("#two li").click(function () {
            $("#two").hide();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This is working fine but is there a way to hide the menu if i click second image?